# Test Automation for API tests

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, phantomjs

I would like to set up automated tests, to test APIs.
To be more precise, for example I want to send out HTTP Requests (POSTS) and test the Responses. Therefore, it got to be headless browser testing.

I have setup Selenium along with NUnit and Phantom JS as a Driver. Tests are written in C# and I am using Visual Studio as an IDE.

I have been googling a lot, but I dont seem to find particular answers to my questions for the combination mentioned above.

Does the combination above allow me to write tests to test APIs or rather send and receive HTTP Requests and Responses ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with Selenium. Test API's usingthe basic `HttpResponse` & request objects within C# and test **websites** through Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can answer my question through the last few months of experience. I write automated tests to send out test requests such as post, get, put etc and test the outcome using the basic http response body and status codes. that is the easiest way of testing an api. Of course, if anyone wants to test in depth such as load testing, then appropriate tool can be used.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that you might want to consider is using [Runscope](http://www.Runscope.com).  Runscope provides the ability to create tests that send one or more HTTP requests.  You can use information from one request to drive the next request.  You can schedule the tests to run periodically, or you can trigger them using a webhook.
You can also get the tests to run from different data centers around the world for testing response times.

There is a free tier that allows up to 10,000 requests per month.

Disclaimer:  I work as a developer advocate for Runscope.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with NUnit or Phantom JS, but, if your tests are written in C#, I'm wondering if the same code would apply.

I wrote a helper in my test class so I could easily do this over and over:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Submit post request with an arbitrary input model and an arbitrary output model (could be the same model).
    /// URL's of format baseURL/controller/action a la .NET MVC web api, i.e., http://something.com/api/Product/Sales
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="U"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="controller"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="inputModel"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private U DoWebAPIPostRequest<T, U>(string controller, string action, T inputModel)
    {
        string baseURL = "http://localhost:1234/api"; //add your base url for your service here

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string url = baseURL + "api/" + controller + "/" + action;

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(url, inputModel);
            string error = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                U result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<U>().Result;

                return result;
            }
            else throw new Exception(error);

        }
    }
```

Then called it from each test like this (this code assumes you have some POCO's to represent what is coming in and out of your web service- I'm sure you can send and receive text but I'm as familiar with it):

```
Sale saleToAdd = new Sale("...");
RequestResult result= DoWebAPIPostRequest<Sale, RequestResult>("Product", "Sale", saleToAdd);
```

Comment: This is not a unit test. It is perfectly valid but is functional API test. Just because it calls an API doesn't mean it is not a functional test

Comment: @RobbieWareham you're absolutely right. I excised the references to unit tests.  The fact remains that when I did this myself, I was fully, er... mostly aware that I was indeed bastardizing a .NET Unit Test project to do functional tests :-).

Answer (score 0):

I use PhantomJS (actually I normally use CasperJS as a higher-level wrapper around PhantomJS) for testing web services. It is great for this (much better than Selenium, which only wants to act as a browser, so won't let me POST directly to a URL, for instance.)

I have some PhantomJS tests that I control via PHPUnit, so I'm sure you can do the same thing with C# and NUnit. The way I do that is:

1. Build up a JavaScript script in a PHP string
2. Save the PHP string to a temporary file
3. `$command="/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true ".escapeshellarg($temp_filename);`
4. Run `$command` in a shell
5. Delete the temporary file
6. Examine command output to decide if a test pass or fail.

I also run the same tests by using sockets directly, and by using Selenium (telling it to skip tests that require POST-ing data). I like the coverage, because the API being tested will be used both from inside and from outside a browser. If your web services will only be used from inside a browser, PhantomJs testing is all you need; if your web services will only be used from C# code, then using .NET's `HttpClient` object, as shown in another answer, is best.

Comment: Why even involve a browser wrapper? API tests just need a HTTP client. Far faster than headless browser

Comment: @RobbieWareham I test how the API web service calls behave from inside a browser, because they can behave differently from when called from JavaScript in a browser compare to being called from a commandline client. Ideally I'd test the API in every way that my customers might use it; in reality I just try to cover a fair sampling of in-browser and direct. Is that enough explanation of "why" to get you to reverse your downvote? If not, ask again :-)

Comment: YOu should still be able to call an API "browser-like" via HTTP client.  It is only a HTTP call after all.